# SEARCH or COUNTIF excel range with INDIRECT

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, range, countif

I try to make this formula:  `=IF(COUNT(SEARCH(MID(D2;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2)));1);"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))=0;"NO";"OK")`

works like this formula:
`=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"A";"B";"C";"D";"E";"F";"G";"H";"I";"J";"K";"L";"M";"N";"O";"P";"Q";"R";"S";"T";"U";"V";"W";"X";"Y";"Z"};D2))=0;"NO";"OK")`

but its not working when cell starts with no letters.

[image: Image attached]

Comment: Show some input sample data and expected output so that we can suggest.

Comment: Added a print screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are after is probably something like:

```
=IF(SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH(MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",SEQUENCE(26),1),D2),0)),"OK","NO")
```

For versions prior to ms365, try:

```
=IF(IFERROR(LOOKUP(99^99,SEARCH(MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",ROW($1:$26),1),D2)),0),"OK","NO")
```

This is build to be auto-remove implicit intersection so the user won't have to use CSE.

Comment: I dont know how is working with LOOKUP, but its perfect. Im so glad to meet you here. Thank you so much!